# Регулярка, вытащить из строчки содержимое. Мультиязычное

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mod-rewrite

В RewriteRule, использую правило. В нем указано, что необходимо достать по данному условию

```
   m-([a-z-0-9-]+)+
   RewriteRule ^m-([a-z-0-9-]+)+$ index.php?d=$1&p=$2 [QSA]
```

Проблема в том, что срабатывает оно в том случаи если содержит цифры и буквы латинского алфавита.

Как сделать так, чтобы вытащить содержимое. Которое может быть на разных языках и может содержать различные символы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так, возможно в конкретном ЯП нужно что-то дополнительно экранировать:

```
^m-(\p{L}+)+$
```

Только не понятно зачем 2 плюса и группировка, можно упростить:

```
^m-\p{L}+$
```

Comment: `s-222` не хочет работать если присутствуют цифры

Comment: @Aleks если тебе нужно, чтобы строка начиналась с символов "s-", а после этого шли любые символы(от 1 до бесконечности), то тогда вообще всё просто: ^s-.+$

Comment: Ура, работает. Последний вопрос. Если допускаются любы символы, в целом допускается все. Что если пользователь введет к примеру какой нибудь sql код или php. Как в данном случаи можно обезопасить, достаточно ли будет пропустить через `addslashes(strip_tags($_GET['s']))`